# Get a great many counts of questions, by select tags for a date range?

Tags: support, api, questions, tags, rate-limit

I am trying to get the number of questions associated with a specific tag for a particular date range. I initially assumed the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters would do this. However, it appears that filters based on the creation date of the tag itself. So not what I want.

It appears I could use the `/search` route to do this, using a query like:
        [/search?fromdate=1420070400&todate=1454025600&sort=creation&tagged=python](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1420070400&todate=1454025600&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_CXHtXgLFC)

This is not ideal because I am trying to get ~2k tags, month by month, over a few years so I will quickly hit the rate limit.

I want to get how many questions of a particular tag were created every month for the last five years, this is 60 unique date ranges. I want to do this for ~2k tags. So with the available syntax of the search route I would need to make ~120k requests.

Comment: I want to get how many questions of a particular tag were created every month for the last five years, this is 60 unique date ranges. I want to do this for ~2k tags. So with the available syntax of the search route I would need to make ~120k requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the API with far less than 120K requests.  Just use a different approach.
Instead of getting a total for every single month, offload that work to your app.  Use a `/search` query to get the questions for the whole interval in question.  EG:

- [/search?pagesize=100&fromdate=1329523200&todate=1487376000&sort=creation&tagged=python](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#pagesize=100&fromdate=2012-02-18&todate=2017-02-18&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=!-W2eZY)NHKJSvfKX581M&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
  (You will need to request each page of data until `has_more` is false.)

Then use `creation_date` to compute the monthly counts yourself.

You can further reduce the number of API calls by combining tags; EG:
          `...&tagged=python;java...`
and then separating the tags back out again in your own code.

HOWEVER, even this approach will not work for high volume sites & tags.  For example, in 5 years there have been about a million Java questions.  It would take your full 10K quota just to fetch that data (10K calls times 100 questions per call).

So for super high volumes, **the API is not the best tool for this.**
The API was never meant for this kind of data analysis.

**Other tools are provided** for that, mainly the data dumps and [the Data Explorer (SEDE)](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).
For example, [here is a SEDE query that graphs question growth, by month, for select tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison#graph).

[image: Sample graph from SEDE query]

[SEDE also has an API now.](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/You-Can-Now-Play-With-Stack-Overflow-Data-on-Googles-BigQuery/)